# Убрать все символы, кроме латиницы, кириллицы и запятой - PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

подскажите регулярку, которая должна вырезать любые символы, кроме запятой (оставаться должны только кириллица и латинница). Сделал наброски , вроде работают , но запятую не знаю как оставить.

```
$key_words=mb_strtolower($key_words);
$key_words=preg_replace("/[^a-zа-я\s]/iu","",$key_words);
```

Answer (score 15):

Если должны остаться *только* буквы (кириллица + латиница) и запятая, то код должен иметь вид:

```
preg_replace("/[^а-яёa-z,]/iu", '', $target);
```

**UPD:**

Стоит обратить внимание, что регулярное выражение выше соответствует только *части* кириллицы, а именно *русскому алфавиту*. Вообще, понятие кириллица существенно шире, и включает символы, используемые не только в современном русском алфавите, но и в ряде других славянских языков. Кириллические Unicode символы можно увидеть, например, [здесь](http://unicode-table.com/ru/blocks/cyrillic/).

Тоже самое, касается и латиницы. Формально, помимо символов английского алфавита (`/[a-z]/i`), туда входит еще множество других символов, например, `ñ` из испанского алфавита. Регулярное выражение выше, соответствует только символам *английского* алфавита, а не всем символам латиницы.

**UPD2:**

Если же вы действительно хотите оставить в строке символы, которые **формально** входят в латиницу или кириллицу, то вы можете использовать следующий код:

```
preg_replace("/[^,\p{Cyrillic}\p{Latin}]/ui", '', $target);
```

Это регулярное выражение оставляет **очень** большой набор символов (например, кириллические символы `ѥѧѭ`). Не думаю, что его вообще стоит использовать, но для тех, кто формально относится к понятиям *латиница* и *кириллица*, оно может оказаться интересным.

Comment: `\p{Cyrillic}` должен описать все кириллические символы

Comment: Да, действительно. Исправил.

Answer (score 5):

Думаю, раз пользуетесь Юникодом, то и классы знаков нужно от туда использовать:

```
$key_words=preg_replace("/[^\p{L},\s]/u","",$key_words);
```

Тут оставляем `\p{L}` - все буквенные символы, `,` - запятую, `\s` - пробельные символы (для **пробела** нужно заменить на `символ пробела`).

Тестовый пример https://regex101.com/r/wF4gZ2/1

Comment: Модификатор `/u` необходим не только для использования `\p`-классов в самом шаблоне, но и для того, чтобы движок правильно обработал строку в Юникоде. Т.е. необязательно использовать `\p{L}`, но можно (если есть необходимость).

Comment: @stribizhev, это не отменяет того, чтобы использовать `\p{}` классы. Тем более `/а-яё/iu` не вся кириллица, как и `/a-z/iu` не вся латиница.

Comment: @Visman, а что из кириллицы не входит в `/а-яё/iu`? Интересуют символы именно русской кириллицы :)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, http://unicode-table.com/ru/blocks/cyrillic/ В вопросе нет уточнения про русские буквы, есть только `кириллица`.

Comment: @Visman, ок, и какие символы _русской кириллицы_ не входят в `/а-яё/iu`? Это понятно, что кириллица -- понятие описывающее сразу несколько славянских (и не только) языков. Однако применительно к _русскому алфавиту_ диапазон `/а-яё/iu` соответствует всем его буквам. Не нужно вводить людей в заблуждение.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, так и надо писать `символов русского языка`, а не `кириллицы`. Я в заблуждение ни кого не ввожу, это вы не верно формулируете свой ответ.

Comment: @Visman, в чем-то вы правы. Думаю стоит уточнить, `/[\p{L}]+/ui` соответствует, например, строке `ѥѧѭ`. Скорее всего, это будет сюрпризом для ТС.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, вы разве читать не умеете? `\p{L} - все буквенные символы`

Comment: @Visman, и правда... Но тогда ваш ответ не верен вообще. `/[\p{L}]+/ui` соответствует не только кириллице и латинице (см. оригинальный вопрос), но и, например, Ивриту.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, кто вам сказал, что он не верен вообще? В ответе прямо сказано, что данное регулярное выражение пропускает все буквенные символы, запятую и пробелы. В отличии от утверждения в вашем ответе `кириллица + латиница`.

Comment: @Visman, читайте вопрос внимательнее: `(оставаться должны только кириллица и латинница)` :)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, `(оставаться должны только кириллица и латинница)` я это видел с самого начала и поэтому был написан мой ответ, так как в вашем ответе не было `кириллицы` и `латиницы`. Вы так бы его и оставили без изменения не напиши я своего ответа со `всеми буквенными символами`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29611/discussion-between-dmitriy-simushev-and-visman).