# Регулярное выражение для русских/латинских букв, цифр и точки с зяпятой на PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно сделать проверку строки, разрешить только русские/латинские буквы, цифры и точки с запятой.

Знаю что делается это с помощью `preg_match`. Но как?

```
preg_match(" а тут что писать? ",$test)
```

Comment: Нашел Вот такое preg_match("/[^(\w)|(\x7F-\xFF)|(\s)]/",$test) но как сюда добавить точки и запятие?

Comment: Там писать [регулярное выражение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F). Раз речь про php, почитайте их [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php). Это ведь учебное задание?

Comment: Как бы поиск: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/453905/%D0%A3%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-php

Comment: @Анатолий если ответ вас устраивает, отметьте его как "принятый"

Answer (score 2):

Как то так:

```
<?php
// предыдущий код
$str = 'Входная строка с латиницей and other symbol ;';
$countMatch = preg_match_all('/^[a-z0-9а-яё;]+$/iu', $str);
if(!$countMatch) {
    echo "Строка не подходит";
}
// последующий код
?>
```

### UPD

1. Позабыл про флаг `u`, обновил ответ.
2. Действительно в вопросе не было про пробел ничего, почему то захотелось его добавить. Но после замечания @Dmitriy Simushev поправил ответ

Comment: В исходном вопросе вроде бы ни слова не сказано о пробельных символах ;)

Comment: да, зачем же нам ТЗ ))) спасибо, поправил ответ

Comment: А зачем тут функция `preg_match_all()`, если вы проверяете строку разом от начала до конца?

Comment: @Visman, да, в данном случае можно и `preg_match`, разницы никакой