# Регулярное выражение разбирающее числобуквенную строку php?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Доброго времени! Есть такая задаче - я не силен в таких сложных регулярных выражениях - вот хочу попросить помощи! Есть строка примерно такого типа 19Fu2hgrskjre - она содержит цифры и буквы латиницы при том постоянно в одной последовательности: цифры-буквы-цифры-буквы . Задача такая как то разделить ее на 4 переменные - в одной первая последовательность цифр, во второй последовательность букв - в третей опять последовательность цифр и в четвертой соответственно букв. Пробовал через цикл foreach но сами понимаете это бред( вот думаю это можно реализовать через 4 регулярных выражения?

Comment: [`(\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)`?](https://regex101.com/r/uJ4oW9/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно одним регулярным выражением

```
preg_match('/(\d+)([^\d]+)(\d+)([^\d]+)/',"19Fu2hgrskjre",$match);
```

В массиве `$match` получаете свои 4 подстроки, в элементах с `$match[1]` до `$match[4]`

Выражение сделал исходя из `цифры` и `НЕ цифры`. Если возможные буквы надо ограничить, то буквы в регулярке задавать диапазонами на подобии `[a-zA-Z]`

Answer (score 0):

Если вам действительно нужно лишь 4 группы и получить на выходе 4 переменных, то вот так:

```
$inputStr = '19Fu2hgrskjre'; // входная строка
preg_match("/^(\d+)(\w+)(\d+)(\w+)$/ui", $inputStr, $matches); // получаем совпадения с регуляркой
if(count($matches) > 1) { // если нашли совпадения
    list($full, $a, $b, $c, $d) = $matches; // получаем 4 переменные
    echo $a, $b, $c, $d; // используем переменные
}
```

> я не силен в таких сложных регулярных выражениях

Где вы тут нашли "сложные выражения" ума не приложу.

Comment: ну вы поймите я просто еще лах вообще в плане регулярок) ^А-яA-z - мой потолок) по сему и просил помощи)

Comment: Никогда не пишите `А-я` – в этот диапазон во-первых входят лишние символы, а во-вторых не входят `Ёё` – [Вопрос про это](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464340/Регулярное-выражение-для-русских-латинских-букв-цифр-и-точки-с-зяпятой-на-php)

Comment: + спасибо буду знать)