# как убрать спецсимволы в тексте golang

Tags: golang

Допустим есть текст: Привет! как дела? что=-

как сделать чтобы вывелось Приветкакделачто , т.е. удалить все !?=-

Делаю вот так, что еще надо дописать?

https://play.golang.org/p/J1YjwVJbTf

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/453905/%D0%A3%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-php Аналогично регуляркой в Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь регуляркой:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
        var re = regexp.MustCompile(`[[:punct:]]`)
        str := "Привет! как дела? что=-"
        str45 := re.ReplaceAllString(str, "")
        fmt.Println(str45)
}
```

Выведет:

```
Привет как дела что
```

Если нужно удалять ещё и все whitespace-символы, такие как пробел, перенос строки и прочее, регулярку можно чуть-чуть дополнить:

```
var re = regexp.MustCompile(`[[:punct:]]|[[:space:]]`)
```

Результат: https://play.golang.org/p/Lm7kv4aIo2

Comment: Нужно чтобы еще пробелы удалялись

Comment: @Pasha дополнил ответ.

Comment: Всё отлично получилось, спасибо. Результат: https://play.golang.org/p/3RmJVyDgWJ

Comment: а если допустим из txt файла считывать порядком 1000 строк, то регулярка будет быстро работать?

Comment: @Pasha к сожалению, не знаю, попробуйте поискать информацию на эту тему, или провести собственный тест производительности

Comment: Потестил с такими символами, выдает ошибку

https://play.golang.org/p/X7lC2He3MB

Comment: @Pasha это уже ваша ошибка: вы экранируете символ `|` вот тут: `\|` в строке `retert671&<>'\|`~/?,`.

Comment: виноват, сразу не заметил