# Как удалить с строки все кроме букв и цифр

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте!

Есть произвольная срока в ней может быть какие угодно буквы, цифры и символы.

Подскажите как оставить в сроке только буквы и цифры

К примеру: `Съешь $ещё% этих "мягких" <французских> булок, да выпей [же] чаю!?`

Comment: В принципе, это даже дубликат [Убрать все символы, кроме латиницы, кириллицы и запятой - PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/453905/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    $str = 'Съешь $ещё% этих "мягких" <французских> булок, да выпей [же] чаю!?';
    $str2 = preg_replace('/[^ a-zа-яё\d]/ui', '',$str );
    echo $str2;
```

Comment: `/[^ a-zа-яё\d]/ui` при флаге `i` нет необходимости указывать символы в верхнем регистре, в спектре `а-я` нет символа `ё`, `\d` - ну, тут понятно.

Comment: MedvedevDev, поправил)